# Did researchers discover a new type of matter inside neutron stars?

Tags: resource-recommendations, astronomy, quarks, neutron-stars, exotic-matter

I just read the University of Helsinki press release [Researchers discover a new type of matter inside neutron stars](https://phys.org/news/2020-06-neutron-stars.html) on phys.org. It states that a Finnish research group has found strong evidence for the presence of exotic quark matter inside the cores of the largest neutron stars in existence. I want to know whether this is new because I didn't got any research paper discussed that new? any paper for confirmation?

Answer (score 1):

The press release you linked to contains a reference to the paper under discussion,

> E Annala et al, Evidence for quark-matter cores in massive neutron stars, [*Nature Physics* **16**, 907 (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41567-020-0914-9).

Answer (score 0):

No, they didn't really "discover" a new form of matter inside neutron stars.

Firstly, this is a theoretical investigation of the possible equations of state that might govern the interiors of neutron stars. The observational constraints are provided by the requirement that $2M_{\odot}$ neutron stars can exist and that the "tidal deformability" of $1.4 M_{\odot}$ neutron stars lies within a range constrained by the LIGO observations of a neutron star merger.

Secondly, the possibility of "quark matter" or a "quark-gluon plasma" has been hypothesised inside neutron stars certainly since the 1980s. At high densities, the idea is that the quark attain asymptotic freedom and you end up with a gas composed of up, down and strange quarks, that may behave like almost ideal Fermi gases.

What the paper concludes is that the observational constraints, such as they are, favour an equation of state that does feature quark matter at high densities, but that these densities are only reached in the most massive ($\sim 2M_{\odot}$) neutron stars.